# DotNetNuke As OAuth Provider - Can't Find A Good Resource

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN website with registered users.

I need third parties (clients) to be able to forward to that DNN website's login page, and then redirect back to their pages with an access token, so, yes, OAuth.

The problem is, HOW do we get DNN to be able to authenticate this way? It seems like we're stuck with the default login page, and it will just log the user into that DNN website and not redirect back (to the client) with an access token. It seems to me like we would have to do some major heavy plumbing on the DNN website to get this to work.

Is there even such a function that we could readily call that takes in username and password (exactly as typed by the user) and return a value that indicates whether or not the username/password pair is correct? (Then would we think about *how* to generate those tokens.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know that function does not exist. You should build a kind of DNN module to make DNN work as OAuth Provider.

There's a code sample of DotNetOpenAuth [here](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples) which uses OAuth to authenticate users. Probably you will see that there are more examples, and even newer but .. pay attention because If you are using the last version of DNN (7.x), it works using the .NET Framework 4 and the newer samples uses 4.5. So, take a look of the first example! The ASP NET Handler called OAuth.ashx is your OAuth Service provider.

Then, I recommend you adapt that sample code to work as DNN module.

Here are some things that can help you: [DNN Module development](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/module-development). There are some videos which shows the basic of module development.